# Sum values from DF and make a new one

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe in R:

```
ID <- c(rep("ID1" , 4) , rep("ID2" , 4))
mut <- rep(c("AC", "TG", "AG", "TC"), 2) 
count <- c(2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7) 
data.frame(ID, mut, count)

   ID mut count
1 ID1  AC     2
2 ID1  TG     4
3 ID1  AG     6
4 ID1  TC     8
5 ID2  AC     1
6 ID2  TG     3
7 ID2  AG     5
8 ID2  TC     7
```

I want to create a new one where I sum the values of count based on "mut" column.
Basically, for each ID, I would sum the count from mut=AC and TG and from AG and TC, to obtain this:

```
   ID new_mut count
1 ID1  AC-TG     6
2 ID1  AG-TC     14
3 ID2  AC-TG     4
4 ID2  AG-TC     12
```

I have absolutely no clue on how to do this!!

Thanks!!

M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better make sure you have an even number of elements in each ID.

```
df=data.frame(ID, mut, count)

df$sek=rep(1:(nrow(df)/2),each=2)

do.call(rbind,
  by(df,list(df$sek),function(x){
    data.frame(
      "ID"=x$ID[1],
      "new_mut"=paste0(x$mut,collapse="-"),
      "count"=sum(x$count)
    )
  })
)

   ID new_mut count
1 ID1   AC-TG     6
2 ID1   AG-TC    14
3 ID2   AC-TG     4
4 ID2   AG-TC    12
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, and it was much easier than what I though at first, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, val = ceiling(match(mut, unique(mut))/2)) %>%
  summarise(mut = paste0(mut,collapse="-"), 
            count = sum(count)) %>%
  select(-val)

#  ID    mut   count
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 ID1   AC-TG     6
#2 ID1   AG-TC    14
#3 ID2   AC-TG     4
#4 ID2   AG-TC    12
```